# How can I use custom menus with a Bootstrap WordPress theme?

Tags: php, functions, menus, html

I have this 'primary' menu with a few items in the CMS, which I can list nicely with this **PHP code:**

```
$args = array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary'
);

wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

The PHP outputs the menu with the `<ul>` tag. but, I want to use **HTML** that looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">  
    <!-- primary menu items -->
</ul>
```

I'm looking for the right way to output my primary menu with the HTML from above.

Comment: You likely will need a Bootstrap compliant *Menu Walker* to fulfill your needs, perform a (re-)search on the net to find more information on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the classes of the `<ul>` by adding `'menu_class'=>'nav navbar-nav'` to your `$args` array. *Remember, this parameter overwrites all the classes, so add "menu" as well if you want many themes and plugins to work!*

If you don't want the outer `<div>`, you can "unwrap" the `<ul>` by adding `'container'=>false`.

```
$args = array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar-nav',
    'container'      => false,
);
```

See the full reference [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/).

Answer (score 0):

From your question i'm guessing you don't want wrapping divs around your  tags. To remove them just add that extra line to your `$args`. If this is not the answer can you please specify the problem.

```
$args = array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container' => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $args );
```